# $y'' + by' + cy = 0$, where $b,c$ are real constants, find the condition statisfies $\lim_{t\to\infty} y(t) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'' + by' + cy = 0$, where $b,c$ are real constants, find the condition which satisfies 
$$\lim_{t\to\infty} y(t) = 0$$
Here is what I've tried

There are three cases to consider

1. $b^2 - 4c >0$ for $b > \sqrt{b^2 - 4c} > 0, \lim_{t\to\infty} y(t) = 0$

Hence, $b >0, c>0$

2. $b^2 - 4c <0$ for $b >0, \lim_{t\to\infty} y(t) = 0$
3. $b^2 - 4c =0$ for $b > 0, \lim_{t\to\infty} y(t) = 0$

Hence, $b >0, c>0$ is the final answer. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

If the roots of the characteristic equation are real, your differential equation will be something of the form

$y = A e^{r_1 t} + B e^{r_2 t}$

If they are complex, i.e. $a \pm ib$

$y = A e^{a t}\cos bt + B e^{a t}\sin bt$

if $\lim_\limits{t\to \infty} y(t) = 0$ then the real parts of the roots are less than 0.

Either $r_1,r_2$ are both real, and both negative, or the real part of the complex roots is less than zero.

In either case we require $b,c > 0$